# Prevent YouTube related videos

Tags: youtube

Is it possible to stop the related videos from showing after videos? The problem is YouTube freezes for a short period of time after the video ends, I guess because of the related video loading time. This gets extremely annoying, so I usually try to stop them before they end. I searched for an Extension, but couldn't find any.

p.s., This is for YouTube videos in general, I don't need it for my uploaded embed videos!

[image: I marked it with the orange circle]

Comment: Can I ask which browser you are using for Youtube?

Comment: Google Chrome Version 47.0.2526.106 m

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the following extension which prevents related videos showing at the end of the current video, as well as many other things, which I quite like:

[Magic Actions for Youtube](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/magic-actions-for-youtube/abjcfabbhafbcdfjoecdgepllmpfceif)

Please not I am not affiliated with the extension in any way, I am just a user.

I expect it is the "Auto-hide player controls" option which creates this behaviour, accessible from the options cog underneath the video once the extension is installed.

Happy watching!

Comment: Glad to hear it!

Answer (score 1):

On the right next to the video there is an autoplay slider. I have highlighted it as orange in my screenshot. In my case it is disabled.

[image: Youtube Autoplay]

Comment: Not autoplay. I mean when the video ends, it loads 12 related videos which are shown in the videoplayer